# Confusion with Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run some external executable code from within Python and then make use of the output.The code I'm using takes an external file and returns a single number (the number of images encoded in that file). When I run from the command line, I see the following:

```
me@ubuntu:~/nist/hsfsys/bin$ ./nummis  /usr/local/hsfsys/data/by_class/4a/train_4a.mis 
3962
```

Where 3962 is a correct output as near as I can tell

However, when I try to use subprocess from within Python, I get the following error:

```
me@ubuntu:~/nist/hsfsys/bin$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["./nummis","/usr/local/hsfsys/data/by_class/4a/train_4a.mis"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./nummis', '/usr/local/hsfsys/data/by_class/4a/train_4a.mis']' returned non-zero exit status 32
>>> subprocess.call(["./nummis","/usr/local/hsfsys/data/by_class/4a/train_4a.mis"])
3962
32
```

How should I interpret this "non-zero exit status 32" ? If something is wrong, why don't I see it on the command line? If nothing is wrong, why is Python complaining & how can I get it to stop complaining?

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is as documented for the subprocess .check_call() function. I guess you have two major options: wrap your call in an exception handler, or use subprocess.Popen and supply your own handling (check_output() is a wrapper around some .Popen() code).

Another, rather convoluted, way to do this would be to call ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'your_command your_args; exit 0'] to force the subprocess to return zero regardless of what your command returns.  But that's sorta silly.  (You could also re-write the "nummis" command to return EXIT_SUCCESS as appropriate)

Comment: @Jim Dennis Thanks. Using p=subprocess.Popen(.....,stdout=subprocess.PIPE) followed by z=p.communicate() gave me access to the output I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line only reports the exit status when explicitly asked for it.

After calling your program from the command line, try

```
echo $?
```

in order to show the exit status. If it shows `32` as well, it is the called program which is guilty. It doesn't properly `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` in its `main()`.

Comment: echo $? does show 32, which according to /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h. means there is a broken pipe. Thanks.

Comment: @user1245262 This lookup is only valid if the program explicitly returns the value of `errno`. Otherwise, it is up to the program `nummis` itself what its returncodes mean.